# Local install of TinyMCE doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinymce

I use node.js + jade + tinymce.

my tinymce.jade:

```
doctype html
html
 head
    title Test
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    style
       | body { padding-top:80px; }
      //script(type='text/javascript', src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js")
    script(type='text/javascript', src="../tinymce/tinymce.min.js")
    script(type='text/javascript')
     | tinymce.init({selector: "#mytextarea"})
 body
  div.container
   div.jumbotron.text-center
    h1 
     | Test
    p Test:
    textarea(id="mytextarea")
```

With

```
script(type='text/javascript', src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js")
```

it is working. -> Remote use of TinyMCE.

When I use the local install with `script(type='text/javascript', src="./tinymce/tinymce.min.js")` it doesn't work.

The console says:

```
GET /tinymce 304 58.722 ms - -
GET /tinymce/tinymce.min.js 404 2.006 ms - 35
```

Why he asks for another get?
I need to add another route for the js file of TinyMCE?
The install-files of TinyMCE placed in:
test.js/views/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

thank you

Comment: with ckeditor i got the same error, a 404 error on the .js file...

Comment: solved it with: `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));` in app.js